Summation of inverse trigonometry series
$${\tan^{-1}}\frac{1}{3+2\sqrt2} + {\tan^{-1}}\frac{1}{4\sqrt2+3\sqrt3} + {\tan^{-1}}\frac{1}{5\sqrt3+4\sqrt4}+{\tan^{-1}}\frac{1}{6\sqrt4+5\sqrt5}$$ to $24$ terms.
My Approach :
I found the $n^{th}$ terms first.
The $n^{th}$ term of the sequence $$3,4\sqrt{2},5\sqrt{3},6\sqrt{4},...$$ is $(n+2)\sqrt{n}$.
Again the $n^{th}$ term of the sequence $$2\sqrt{2}, 3\sqrt{3}, 4\sqrt{4}, 5\sqrt{5},...$$ is $(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}$
Now I tried to write the series in the form of $n^{th}$ terms. That is the series will be
$$\sum_{n=1}^{24}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+2)\sqrt{n}+(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}}\right)$$
Now I can't understand how to break the numerator.
Please help me

Telescoping series is a great idea. Work on that further. Hint: What is $\cot^{-1} x - \cot^{-1} y$?

$$\cot^{-1}\frac{xy+1}{y-x}$$ @CalvinLin

let $u = \sqrt{n}, v = \sqrt{n+1}$, $\small (n+2)\sqrt{n} + (n+1)\sqrt{n+1}
= (v^2+1)u + (u^2 + 1)v = (u+v)(1+uv) = \frac{1+uv}{v-u}$

@achillehui thanks so much, was writing 2nd term as v^3

@IITASPIRANT Can you write up a solution to this problem then?

Noticing that $$
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{1}{(n+2) \sqrt{n}+(n+1) \sqrt{n+1})}\\= & \frac{1}{(n+2) \sqrt{n}+(n+1) \sqrt{n+1}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}} \\
= & \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{(n+2) \sqrt{n(n+1)}+(n+1)^2-(n+2) n -(n+1) \sqrt{n(n+1)} }\\
= & \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n(n+1)}},
\end{aligned}
$$
therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+2) \sqrt{n}+(n+1) \sqrt{n+1}}\right) & =\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n+1} \sqrt{n}}\right) \\
& =\tan ^{-1}(\sqrt{n+1})-\tan ^{-1} \sqrt{n}
\end{aligned}
$$
is telescoping and hence, in general,
$$
\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^{m}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+2) \sqrt{n}+(n+1) \sqrt{n+1}}\right)  =\tan ^{-1} \sqrt{m+1}-\frac{\pi}{4}}
$$
In particular,

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{24}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+2) \sqrt{n}+(n+1) \sqrt{n+1}}\right)  =\tan ^{-1} 5-\frac{\pi}{4}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+2) \sqrt{n}+(n+1) \sqrt{n+1}}\right)  =\frac{\pi}{4}
$$


By
$$\tan ^{-1}(\text{x$\_$})+\tan ^{-1}(\text{y$\_$}):\to \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-x y}\right), \  |x y|<1$$
give it a try in Mathematica repeated
   Plus @@ ArcTan[{1/(3 + 2 Sqrt[2]), 
                   1/(4 Sqrt[2] + 3 Sqrt[3]), 
                   1/(5 Sqrt[3] + 4 Sqrt[4]), 
                   1/( 6 Sqrt[4] + 5 Sqrt[5])}] //. 
              {ArcTan[x_] + ArcTan[y_] :>  ArcTan[(x + y)/(1 - x y)]} //
             $$\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$$

$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2}+3 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}+3}}{1-\frac{1}{\left(2 \sqrt{2}+3\right) \left(4 \sqrt{2}+3 \sqrt{3}\right)}}+\frac{\frac{1}{5 \sqrt{5}+12}+\frac{1}{5 \sqrt{3}+8}}{1-\frac{1}{\left(5 \sqrt{3}+8\right) \left(5 \sqrt{5}+12\right)}}}{1-\frac{\left(\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2}+3 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}+3}\right) \left(\frac{1}{5 \sqrt{5}+12}+\frac{1}{5 \sqrt{3}+8}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{1}{\left(2 \sqrt{2}+3\right) \left(4 \sqrt{2}+3 \sqrt{3}\right)}\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{\left(5 \sqrt{3}+8\right) \left(5 \sqrt{5}+12\right)}\right)}}\right)$$
  %//FullSimplify

$$\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(3-\sqrt{5}\right)\right)$$
Confirmed numerically. If the condition is not met,  a $\pi$ and sign changes may occur if the result is in the left complex half plane.
